# How can I target my message to a specific URL using MassTransit and MSMQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, msmq, masstransit

As per my understanding, MSMQ broadcasts messages and and the subscribers who have subscribed for the given type will accept and process that message.

I was wondering If I could target my outgoing message to a specific server rather than broadcasting it all over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an endpoint factory you can use to create an `IEndpoint`. From there, call `Send()` and it will send the message directly to that endpoint.

Comment: I created an endpoint like this : var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("msmq://localhost/get_queue");

Where is the Send method ?

Comment: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/v2.8.0/src/MassTransit/IEndpoint.cs#L78, it's on `IEndpoint`. Use `IServiceBus.GetPoint(...)` to get an `IEndpoint` - https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/v2.8.0/src/MassTransit/IServiceBus.cs#L174. That takes care of making sure you use the right IEndpointFactory and use the EndpointCache as well.